# How do you construct an Azure Search query to return a wildcard search based solely on a specific field?

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

If I may have missed this in some other area of SO please redirect me but I don't think this is a duped question.

I am using Azure Search with an index field called Title which is searchable and filterable using a Standard Lucerne Analyzer.

When using the built-in explorer, if I want to return all Job Titles that are explicitly named Full Stack Developer I can achieve it this way:

```
$filter=Title eq 'Full Stack Developer'&$count=true
```

But if I want to retrieve all the Job Titles using a wildcard to return all records having Full Stack in the name this way:

```
$filter=Title eq 'Full Stack*'&$count=true
```

The first 20 or so records returned are spot on, but after that point I get a mix of records that have absolutely nothing in common with the Title I specified in the query. My initial assumption was that perhaps Azure was including my specified Title performing an inclusive keyword search on the text as well.

Though I found a few instances where that hypothesis seemed to prove out, so many more of the records returned invalidated that altogether.

Maybe I don't understand fully the mechanics under the hood of Azure Search and so though my query appears to be valid; my expectation of the result is way off.

So how should my query look to perform a wildcard resulting to guarantee the words specified in the search to be included in the Titles returned, if this should be possible? And what would be the correct syntax to condition the return to accommodate for OR operators to be inclusive?

Comment: Basically you would want to perform wildcard search on just `Title` field. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, only the Title field

Answer (score 1):

Azure Cognitive Search allows you to perform wildcard searches limited to specific fields only. To do so, you will need to specify the name of the fields in which you want to perform the search in `searchFields` parameter.

Your search URL in this case would be something like:

```
https://accountname.search.windows.net/indexes/indexname/docs?api-version=2020-06-30&searchFields=Title&search=Full Stack*
```

From the link [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#query-parameters):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That gets me a bit closer and greatly reduces the result which is what I was after but now I'm getting back Titles with names such as: Technical Recruiter (Full Cycle), Full Time Warehouse Position and Commercial Painter - Full Time. So there is still something missing. I suspect Azure is honoring the query b/c all those names contain Full but Stack is missing. I would have expected the first 2 words in the query to always be returned.

Comment: Can you try by putting your search criteria in double quotes? Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-simple-syntax#keyword-search-on-terms-and-phrases. HTH.

Comment: You can include "searchMode=all" as a query parameter to tell azure search to make sure every term in the search request is included in the result

Comment: Double-quotes didn't resolve nor setting searchMode=all. I'm more baffled at this point than upon the initial post.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share some sample data?

Comment: You mean post a couple of records in OData format? Sorry, not certain of the request

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to perform a wildcard against a specific field. I am performing two wildcard searches here against two different fields:

```
queryType=full&search=YourField1Name:(/.*YourSearchForField1.*/) AND YourField2Name:(/.*YourSearchForField2.*/)
```

Note - the uppercasing of 'AND' is important

Hope that helps (it took me a while to get this working :-))